# Set up health check for Sagemaker endpoint in Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, ping, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to set up the health check for a model deployed in Sagemaker.

I am using `/ping` to set up the health check endpoint using this snippet of code:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    """Determine if the container is working and healthy. We declare
    it healthy if we can load the model successfully."""
    health = ScoringService.get_model() is not None

    status = 200 if health else 404
    return flask.Response(response='\n', status=status, mimetype='application/json')
```

I already have assumed a AWS Role and am getting predictions using `/invocations` but when I try calling the `GET https://runtime.sagemaker.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/endpoints/{{endpoint}}/ping`, I am receiving this error:

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

For Authorization, I am using Type AWS Signature, and header is Content-Type: application/json. I think I am missing something in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Because the SageMaker Runtime API is a managed service for inference, there does not appear to be a /ping method available unless you are implementing your own model with SageMaker hosting services.

To verify the status of the inference endpoint, you should call describeEndpoint to check the Status property to validate that it is InService - see here:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.describe_endpoint

An alternative approach for monitoring would be to leverage CloudWatch:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatch.html